# Removing NA from correlation outputs

Tags: r, correlation

When produce a correlation matrix on a large dataset, there are multiple variables that have the same value throughout, hence a correlation can't be done and an NA is outputted. My question is how do I remove all rows and columns with these NA values, or account for this flaw prior to outputting a correlation matrix. So for example in this example...

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:10, 3*8, replace=TRUE), ncol=3))
df$V4 <- rep(3, times = 8)
df$V5 <- rep(2, times = 8)
correlation <- cor(df)
```

I have tried different ways of overcoming this, firstly by adding a use to the correlation calcuation...

```
correlation_two <- cor(df, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
```

But this has no influence. I have also tried various ways of removing NA values but none of these seem to work.

```
output1 <- na.omit(correlation)
output2 <- correlation[complete.cases(correlation),]
output3 <-correlation[,colSums(is.na(correlation))==0]
output4 <- correlation[, !colSums(is.na(correlation)) >1,drop=FALSE] #Removing columns
output4 <- output4[!rowSums(is.na(output4)) >1,drop=FALSE,]#Then rows
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not specifically, unless you can remove or filter out those columns with a standard deviation of zero before the correlation?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's best to prevent the problem than to solve it afterwards.

Identify columns that only have one value:

```
select_for_correlation <- sapply(df,function(x)(length(unique(x))>1))
```

Then do the analysis:

```
res <- cor(df[,select_for_correlation])
    > res
            V1          V2          V3
V1  1.00000000 -0.06801818 -0.04626592
V2 -0.06801818  1.00000000 -0.21533949
V3 -0.04626592 -0.21533949  1.00000000
```

Comment: That works perfectly thank you! I will tick when it allows in 2 minutes.